# Error in the solving of the simultaneous Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

As I am trying to get the solution of the simultaneous ordinary differential equations

```
      b1'[z]-1I*beta1*b1[z]-C1*b2[z]==0, 
      b2'[z]-1I*beta2*b2[z]+C1*b1[z]==0
```

with boundary conditions

```
b1[1.581825567*10^-6]==0.876212, b2[1.581825567*10^-6]==0.481925
```

By running the following command

```
S = DSolve[{b1'[z]-1I*beta1*b1[z]-C1*b2[z]==0, b2'[z]-1I*beta2*b2[z]+C1*b1[z]==0, 
    b1[1.581825567*10^-6]==0.876212, b2[1.581825567*10^-6]==0.481925,
    (b1[z])^2      (b2[z])^2==1}, {b1, b2}, z]
```

I am getting the values of `b1[z]` and `b2[z]`. But my main problem is that whatever the values of `b1[z]` and `b2[z]`, I am getting after solving the above equation, the sum of there values i.e.`|b1|^2+|b2|^2` should be less then or equal to 1, i.e., `|b1|^2+|b2|^2 <= 1` (which is my third boundary condition); so please can anyone suggest me that how I will run the above equation with this third boundary condition `|b1|^2+|b1|^2 <=1`. So that I can get those values of `b1[z]` and `b2[z]` which are satisfying our third boundary condition i.e.`|b1|^2+|b2|^2`. Even I had tryied to run this programme with my third boundary condition. But it is showing some error whose snapshot I am attaching with this problem so please suggest me the right answer for the same problem. And please I have request just do no put simple comment, if it is possible try this problem in mathematica and then send to me.

[image]

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The code you posted seems to be missing a plus sign in your algebraic constraint that you called "third boundary condition."

Answer (score 4):

We have seen this problem posted by you before. This time you don't seem to understand that you can't have more equations than you have dependent variables. You have three equations

```
b1'[z] - 1 I*beta1*b1[z] - C1*b2[z] == 0
b2'[z] - 1 I*beta2*b2[z] + C1*b1[z] == 0
(b1[z])^2 + (b2[z])^2 == 1
```

and only two dependent variables, `b1` and `b2`. That one of the equations is not a *differential* equation doesn't mean it isn't a member of the system.

You may think as the last equation as a constraint, but `DSolve` doesn't see it that way.

Comment: i am not getting man what you are telling.....what is the meaning that ''it doesn't mean it doesn't count.'' and my question is  then what will be the values of b1[z] and b2[z] at that condition can you send me yours code which gives the values values of b1 and b2. otherwise give the answer it is not solvable. or you can tell me if we are getting the values of b1 and b2 with starting two boundary conditions then how we will draft these values of b1 and b2 so that it will satisfy ours third condition

Comment: @AshishkumarAshishkumar. I mean that all three of equations I show in my answer are considered as part of your system by `DSolve`, not just the first two. `DSolve` has no concept of constraint. The message you are seeing is  `DSolve`'s way of telling you it can not solve your system as you are formulating it.

Comment: then can you suggest me how we should go through it. so that we can find the right answer as per our need. or some different technique which you think it can give the answer

Comment: @AshishkumarAshishkumar. I think you need a formulate a better model. Since I have no idea of what kind of physical system you are studying, I can't make any really helpful suggestions. Probably couldn't even if you described the system, because it's not likely I would have expertise in your area. Besides, formulation of a model from observational or theoretical considerations is not on-topic for this site. Sorry.

Comment: one way would be to differentiate the last equation and use it to eliminate the second equation. Then the question would be are the first and the new second equation compatible?

Answer (score 3):

Your ODE is linear, so whether it can satisfy your constraint `|b1|^2+|b2|^2 <= 1` depends primarily on the eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix, as well as the initial condition.

The coefficient matrix is the second array returned by [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html).

```
ode = {b1'[z] - 1 I*beta1*b1[z] - C1*b2[z] == 0, 
   b2'[z] - 1 I*beta2*b2[z] + C1*b1[z] == 0} /. Equal -> Subtract
Normal@CoefficientArrays[ode, {b1[z], b2[z]}]
(*
  {-I beta1 b1[z] - C1 b2[z] + b1'[z], C1 b1[z] - I beta2 b2[z] + b2'[z]}

  {{b1'[z], b2'[z]},              derivatives
   {{ -I beta1,  -C1      },      linear coefficient matrix
    {  C1,       -I beta2 }}}
*)
```

Here are the [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html):

```
lambda = Eigenvalues@CoefficientArrays[ode, {b1[z], b2[z]}][[2]]
(*
  {-(1/2) I (beta1 + beta2 - I Sqrt[-beta1^2 + 2 beta1 beta2 - beta2^2 - 4 C1^2]),
   -(1/2) I (beta1 + beta2 + I Sqrt[-beta1^2 + 2 beta1 beta2 - beta2^2 - 4 C1^2])}
*)
```

There are conditions on the eigenvalues and the initial conditions that have to be satisfied for the constraint to be met.  The conditions on the eigenvalues are relatively simple and will be shown below.  Given that the system has appropriate eigenvalues, then initial condition has to be chosen such that the maximum of `|b1|^2+|b2|^2` is less than or equal to `1`. The conditions for this might be complicated in terms of the symbolic parameters `beta1`, `beta2`, and `C1`.  It shouldn't be too hard to determine for numeric parameters. I'll leave that to the reader

With respect to the eigenvalues, for the solution to meet the constraint for all time, the real parts of the eigenvalues need to be zero.  We can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to simplify the resulting restrictions on the parameters in the ODE:

```
Reduce[Thread[Re[lambda] == 0]]
(* Im[beta1 + beta2] == 0 && Re[Sqrt[-beta1^2 + 2 beta1 beta2 - beta2^2 - 4 C1^2]] == 0 *)
```

If the constraint is to be met only for all **future** time (from the initial condition onward), then the real part of the eigenvalues need only be less than or equal to zero.  The constraints on the parameters then simplify to the following:

```
Reduce[Thread[Re[lambda] <= 0]]
(*
(Im[beta1 + beta2] < 0 && 
   Im[beta1 + beta2] <=
    Re[Sqrt[-beta1^2 + 2 beta1 beta2 - beta2^2 - 4 C1^2]] <=
     -Im[beta1 + beta2]) ||
 (Im[beta1 + beta2] == 0 && 
   Re[Sqrt[-beta1^2 + 2 beta1 beta2 - beta2^2 - 4 C1^2]] == 0)
*)
```

Comment: After studying urs ans again and again.still i am not clear what you want to tell through this above mentioned programme becz still my answer is not completed. because finally i need the b1 and b2 values with my mentioned bou. cond.(bcs), because you did not write anywhere bcs or if you want to tell these above mentioned eigenvalues are values of b1 and b2, then it is giving an error message.I am suggesting you the beta1, beta2, and C1 values, which are at my previously mentioned bcs are beta1 =7.012e+06 and beta2=7.0e+06 and C1=1.522*10^11. please if it possible suggest your ans with code.

Comment: @AshishkumarAshishkumar If `beta1 == beta2` and all three parameters are real, then `|b1|^2+|b2|^2` should remain bounded. (Note beta1, beta2, and C1 are not called boundary conditions traditionally; bcs and initial conditions are values for `b1` and `b2` at specific times.)  The problem is for you to figure out is whether bcs lead to `|b1|^2+|b2|^2` being bounded by `1`. This is all standard theory for linear systems of ODEs and found in most first courses; perhaps you might need to review a textbook on it.

Comment: thanx....sir i will ry to follow any book on ODE then i will discuss you the next............thanx for yours time and support